# Nuxtjs: Ajax call to Mongo succeeds but successive calls don't always work

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm building my first Nuxt app. In my index.vue file I'm making a call to save a post and then retrieve it. I can see that it gets into my MongoDB but it doesn't always invoke my remaining calls correctly -- mainly to retrieve the latest posts after a successful save and then clear the UI. Here you can see my onSubmit() method waits for a response and then retrieves the posts and clears the UI at the same time. Shouldn't this work ok? How come savePost() always works but this.getPosts() and this.clear() mostly fail? Is calling input.focus() interfering with clearing my value?

```
export default {
  components: {},
  data: () => ({
    posts:[],
    confession: ""
  }),
  mounted(){
    this.getPosts();
  },
  methods: {
    async getPosts() {
      let res = await this.$store.dispatch('getPosts');
      this.posts = res;
    },
    async savePost(payload) {
      let res = await this.$store.commit('savePost', payload)
      return res;
    },
    clear(){
      const input = document.querySelector('textarea');
      input.focus();
      input.value = '';
    },
    onSubmit() {
      const input = document.querySelector('textarea').value;
      const res = this.savePost(input);
      res 
        .then((res) => {
          this.playSound(); 
          this.getPosts(); 
          this.clear();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(`Error saving new post: ${err}`);
        });
    },
    playSound: function(){
        var playPromise = document.querySelector('audio').play();
        // In browsers that don’t yet support this functionality,
        // playPromise won’t be defined.
        if (playPromise !== undefined) {
          playPromise.then(function() {
            // Automatic playback started!
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // Automatic playback failed.
            // Show a UI element to let the user manually 
start playback.
          });
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should remove all the document.querySelector's and use a v-model on the textarea, and a ref on the audio element

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - thank you, that was helpful. one last question -- in my onSubmit() method is it correct to have the res.then() handler and successive calls there or is it better placed somewhere else? like in the savePost() handler? the reason i ask is that when i test and add posts very quickly sometimes the call to getPosts() doesn't work.

Comment: yeah, there is abit of refactoring you could do, inc adding validation etc but doing things in a then callback is fine, you don't need to use async/await on your methods, for example, you could do `this.$store.dispatch('getPosts').then(posts => this.posts = posts)` and it will update when its resolved, savePost could just `return this.$store.commit('savePost', payload)`, is no reason to await a promise then return a promise, but the main thing is you want to stick with just using models, the dom could change and you may get race condition on document.querySelector causing it not to find things

Comment: @LawrenceCherone -- i do need to await a promise in save post because that's what the store is returning: export const mutations = {
    async savePost(state, data) {
        let res = await this.$axios.post('/posts', {post: data});
        return res;
    }
}. What I'm seeing now is more about MongoDB performance. The savePost call will work and the GET call is then made but it takes a few seconds for it to actually get inserted into the DB -- which is curious. That's the last problem i'm solving for. But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please do not post code snippet in comments. On the opposite of @LawrenceCherone, I'd recommend sticking to a single and modern `async/await` way for all the API calls.